# How to estimate a population proportion that has a certain disease

Tags: r, population, proportions

I have this data (listed as reproducible):

```
 structure(list(age = c(62.84998, 60.33899, 52.74698, 42.38498
 ), death = c(0, 1, 1, 1), sex = c("male", "female", "female", 
 "female"), hospdead = c(0, 1, 0, 0), slos = c(5, 4, 17, 3), d.time = c(2029, 
 4, 47, 133), dzgroup = c("Lung Cancer", "Cirrhosis", "Cirrhosis", 
 "Lung Cancer"), dzclass = c("Cancer", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", 
 "Cancer"), num.co = c(0, 2, 2, 2), edu = c(11, 12, 12, 11), income = c("$11-$25k", 
 "$11-$25k", "under $11k", "under $11k"), scoma = c(0, 44, 0, 
 0), charges = c(9715, 34496, 41094, 3075), totcst = c(NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), totmcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
 NA_real_, NA_real_), avtisst = c(7, 29, 13, 7), race = c("other", 
 "white", "white", "white"), sps = c(33.8984375, 52.6953125, 20.5, 
 20.0976562), aps = c(20, 74, 45, 19), surv2m = c(0.262939453, 
 0.0009999275, 0.790893555, 0.698974609), surv6m = c(0.0369949341, 
 0, 0.664916992, 0.411987305), hday = c(1, 3, 4, 1), diabetes = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0), dementia = c(0, 0, 0, 0), ca = c("metastatic", "no", 
 "no", "metastatic"), prg2m = c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.899999619), prg6m = c(0.25, 
 0, 0.5, 0.5), dnr = c("no dnr", NA, "no dnr", "no dnr"), dnrday = c(5, 
 NA, 17, 3), meanbp = c(97, 43, 70, 75), wblc = c(6, 17.0976562, 
 8.5, 9.09960938), hrt = c(69, 112, 88, 88), resp = c(22, 34, 
 28, 32), temp = c(36, 34.59375, 37.39844, 35), pafi = c(388, 
 98, 231.65625, NA), alb = c(1.7998047, NA, NA, NA), bili = c(0.19998169, 
 NA, 2.19970703, NA), crea = c(1.19995117, 5.5, 2, 0.79992676), 
     sod = c(141, 132, 134, 139), ph = c(7.459961, 7.25, 7.459961, 
     NA), glucose = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
     bun = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), urine = c(NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), adlp = c(7, NA, 1, 0), adls = c(7, 
     1, 0, 0), sfdm2 = c(NA, "<2 mo. follow-up", "<2 mo. follow-up", 
     "no(M2 and SIP pres)"), adlsc = c(7, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am wanting to estimate the population proportion of individuals who had lung cancer listed as their primary disease group (dzgroup). How would I do this? My original thought was to just divide the total number that have lung cancer by the whole dataset population, but I do not believe this is correct.

Comment: Do you need `mean(df1$dzgroup == "Lung Cancer", na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] 0.5`

Comment: @akrun I don't believe I would need the mean. I am looking for an estimate of the population proportion out of the entire population of my dataset. This proportion would then also tell me what percentage of the population had lung cancer. So if the resulting proportion was 0.1325 (for example) I could say that 13.25% of the population had lung cancer. If that makes sense

Comment: The `mean` of logical vector is the proportion

Comment: This makes sense. So if I wanted to say what percentage of the population had lung cancer it would just be multiplied by 100 to give 50% in this example.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

If we want to get the proportion on the whole data, create a logical vector and get the `mean` as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0, the `mean` will be the proportion of 1s and multiplying by 100 gives the percentage

```
round(100 * mean(df1$dzgroup == "Lung Cancer", na.rm = TRUE), 2)
```